# How do I host and edit a JSON file separate from my GitHub repository?

Tags: json, github, heroku

I'm building a Discord bot and am trying to host it with Heroku and GitHub. I intend to store user data in a JSON file but cannot figure out how to edit the JSON file because I cannot edit it while it is in the repository. I am hoping there is a way to do it through Heroku, without using a separate website.

Note: I know how you would normally edit the JSON file, but because it is in a GitHub Repository it doesn't work the normal way.

Comment: You could store a JSON file on a service like S3, but then it's read-only (you could "edit" it by uploading a new file). If the data needs to change often and programmatically, a service like Firebase would be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a file as a database. Use a *database* as a database.

This is generally good advice, but especially important on Heroku where the [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) prevents changes to files from persisting long-term.

[Heroku Postgres](https://www.heroku.com/postgres) is a relatively easy way to get started. Its base plan is free.

Comment: So, Only Issue With This Is... Some People Only Wish To Store Short Term, And Worker Dynos do not support ephemeral fs Like Web Dynos do, your code Needs to be almost straight JS, any module from any framework usually doesn't allow you to even edit the file with worker dynos attached, This is what allot of bot devs for discord run into, so they often abandon Heroku and use AWS or other hosting platforms with cache based fs or live filesystems.

Comment: @PandaDev, what does that have to do with anything? Short-term or long-term, use a _database_ if you want a database.

Comment: *I'm saying, storing in a db can increase load times for things that need to be accessed quickly then discarded, such as an index of people playing a game to prevent them from starting a new one but once the game is finished it just deletes the id of the player from the index.* It would be simpler to use AWS in that situation as Node's FS still works.

Comment: @PandaDev, so use Memcached or Redis or something. A proper data store, not a file.

Comment: I was never saying redis was a bad idea, I was implicating the idea that beginners may have issues learning massive modules or even frameworks, I don’t have any suggestions besides using AWS anyways so I don’t mind this thread of comments anymore. However thank you for giving input that’s a big thing in programming (problem solving).

Answer (score 0):

I believe GitLab allows you to edit files in place, and they have a free tier like Github. As mentioned by Chris, this is generally not recommended, but it may work for your needs.

https://about.gitlab.com/